# Display results from past days

Tags: php, mysql

I try to get last 7 days records using php and mysql. I am saving the results in database dd-mm-yyyy format.

```
$start = date('d-m-Y',strtotime('-7 days'));
$end = date('d-m-Y',strtotime('now'));

mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) FROM `registration_form` WHERE `appointment_date` BETWEEN '$start' and '$end' and `registration_type` = 'provisional_registration'"));
```

from this code i get the records from last 7 days but some time its not give  accurate results.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: What are you assuming by **[...] some time its not give accurate results.** ? What type is your SQL table column which contains the date you are trying to extract ?

Comment: i need mysql records of last 7 days in php with 100% accurate

Comment: Tell us **what** is wrong with your results.

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: example : SELECT count(*) FROM `complaint` WHERE `complaint_date` BETWEEN '20-01-2015' and '27-01-2015'

Comment: no error bt i need any other method for get results

Comment: If you say that the results are inaccurate then it must be something wrong with them. What exactly is wrong with the results? They are out of given date/time range? Are there missing results? Perhaps results that do not belong there?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',time()-(7*86400)); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registration_form WHERE appointment_date <='$date' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) FROM `registration_form` WHERE `appointment_date` BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and `registration_type` = 'provisional_registration'");
```